# Best pattern to query items to exclude a subset of known keys in DynamoDB?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I’m making a game where players play levels. There’s no order  (which is what I want to serve dynamically).

I want to serve a player all the levels they haven’t played, even when new levels are created. The problem is that this is a NOT and JOIN operation, which obviously doesn’t exist in dynamodb. Is there an approach for it?

I could keep an index on level createTime and save the lastPlayedCreateTime to a player object, then query for all the levels after that time. However then I’m stuck to just that index. Is there a good pattern for this? Eg I can’t change it to serve on unplayed levels ordered by “level difficulty”.

Right now I make 2 queries: for all the levels a user has played, and then all the levels globally, and filter out/sort and serve then from my application. It feels like there could be a better way, if there are lots of each then this doesn’t really work.

I do this primarily with the following PK and SK: [UID#userId, LVL#lvlId] to query for stats for a level per player, and [LVL, LVL#lvlid] to query for all levels.

another example: how does Tinder show people you haven’t seen before? (While maybe changing the ordering)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting puzzle. It's fundamentally an algorithm question. The question is whether there's an algorithm that would do this efficiently even at scale.

Seems like you may have an assumption that if you could just express a join then things would be good, but that join could be extremely costly at scale. That's why DynamoDB doesn't let you have something that's simple to express but difficult to execute. It makes the painful look non-painful.

You don't give stats on most key things that impact a design like this. I'm going to make assumptions. I'll assume there's 100 difficulties, each with a million levels (IDs), there's a million players, players can have played a majority of levels, and new levels get added randomly over time with various difficulties on each.

You're presently following a design where you exhaustively list all the levels a player has played and cross-check that with the list of levels out there. This is inherently O(n) with the number of levels. Not great. If this person has played 999,999 levels it's going to take you a lot of work to find that 1 remaining level.

I like your idea more that you just keep a "bookmark" for each player with their progress within each difficulty. Then you can just fetch the next level after the bookmark for the given difficulty and update the bookmark.

So, levels are added with a PK of their `difficulty` and an SK of their `creationTime`. Extra attributes include the lookup ID or whatever.

Players are added with a PK of the player ID and an SK as a compound `<difficulty>#<creationTimeBookmark>`.

| PK | SK | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UID#1 | DIFF#1#2022-01-05 |  |
| UID#1 | DIFF#2#2022-01-05 |  |
| UID#2 | DIFF#1#2022-01-07 |  |
| UID#2 | DIFF#2#2022-01-06 |  |
| DIFF#1 | 2022-01-05 | ID#a |
| DIFF#1 | 2022-01-06 | ID#b |
| DIFF#1 | 2022-01-07 | ID#c |
| DIFF#2 | 2022-01-05 | ID#d |
| DIFF#2 | 2022-01-06 | ID#e |
| DIFF#2 | 2022-01-07 | ID#f |

To find the next level for a player you figure out what difficulty you want, query for their current bookmark with that difficulty, fetch the next item after that bookmark, then update the player with that new bookmark. It's a simple: get, query, update of singleton values.

As you add new levels, they go to the end so it just works fine.

If you want something closer to **randomness** then I might suggest starting each player with a random starting bookmark for each difficulty and enabling loop-around so when you hit the end you start at the beginning. To handle adds you'll need to keep track of their starting point and loop point so when they're so far along they meet their original starting point you can resume just going forward at the loop point.

Comment: Thanks for the thought out reply, you've understood my question perfectly.

I was trying to find more information about similar problems like this that exist, but it's hard to search for. I figured any app that serves content for users probably comes across a similar issue, perhaps time indexing solves most of that. 

The "bookmark" approach seems probably the best right now, I'll have to give it a little more thought about things like skipping levels. If I wanted to change the index to anything new, I might have to run some batch job to update player's bookmarks as a general solve.